# Replacing 3rd gear synchro on a Tacoma

Tags: toyota, transmission, gears, tacoma

I have a 4WD 2007 Tacoma V6 manual with 6 speeds.  This model has a notorious reoccurring problem with its 3rd gear, which is due to the synchro going bad on that gear, as per many online testimonials.  The problem manifests itself on my truck by grinding when I am shifting into the 3rd gear, unless I do it super slowly keeping the clutch pressed all the way.

I would like to fix it and replace the synchro but would like to first gauge the level of complexity involved.  I am a fairly competent DIY mechanic who has done many different types of repairs without failures that required professional assistance.  Is this repair something that involves a special tool that only specialty shops have?

Answer (score 4):

See if [the instructions located on this page](http://www.customtacos.com/tech.old/files/05FSM/repair.html) will help you decide. Manual transmissions, while easier to deal with than automatics, are nothing to be trifled with. If you don't have a *lot* of mechanical know how, it's not something to be tackling on your own. If you get it apart and cannot put it back together again, a tranny shop is going to not want to take it off your hands. If you are trying to save money, the easiest thing to do is take it out of the vehicle and then take it to a shop to get done. Save you loads on labor.

Comment: do you think it is possible to convert a floor jack into a tranny jack ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another car or is this your sole daily? if the latter definitely have a shop do it. I've done a couple manuals and while not impossible it's a little overwhelming when you see all the pieces on the floor in front of you. Bag and label every single part and take as many pictures as possible. You'll also need a press and bearing separator to pull stuff off shafts. Have to be extremely diligent with various tolerances as you go to.